# Why does `object.__init__` take no args

Tags: python, python-3.x

Why doesn't `object.__init__` take `*args, **kwargs` as arguments? This breaks some simple code in a highly annoying manner without any upsides as far as I can see:

Say we want to make sure that all `__init__`'s of all parent classes are called. As long as every init follows the simple convention of calling `super().__init__` this will guarantee that the whole hierarchy is run through and that exactly once (also without ever having to specify the parent specifically). The problem appears when we pass arguments along:

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print("foo-init")
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs) # error if there are arguments!

class Bar:
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print("bar-init")
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

class Baz(Bar, Foo):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print("baz-init")
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

b1 = Baz() # works
b2 = Baz("error")
```

What's the reasoning for this and what's the best general (! it's easily solvable in my specific case but that relies on additional knowledge of the hierarchy) workaround? The best I can see is to check whether the parent is object and in that case not give it any args.. horribly ugly that.

Comment: Usually you should know what the parent is, and not simply pass in arbitrary arguments.

Comment: @jadkik For one that violates DRY and not necessarily if I'm writing a mixin. But yes in lots of cases there's an easy workaround and MI is not that a good idea in most cases anyhow. So yes I'm more interested in the reasoning behind this, but if there's a nice general solution, that would still be interesting imo.

Comment: By that logic, EVERY `__init__()` method in every class anyone ever writes in Python needs to take `*args` and `**kwargs`, even if just to throw them away.  Which doesn't make much sense.  And makes it even more difficult to figure out what to do with named args (do you have to append them to `args` and/or `kwargs` before passing them up the chain?  Just drop them?)  It also breaks OO, as then all params for the `__init__()` of the nth subclass end up in the `__init__()` of the parent without any control.

Comment: @sr2222 If it's expected to be used in an arbitrary inheritance hierarchy? Yes. Inheritance is an often overused solution (composition works better often enough) and the situations in which you expect "arbitrary" inheritance hierarchies with MI are even rarer. So no problem for 99.9% of all classes out there, but for `object` as the base class of every object? Yes I'd expect that to handle this.

Comment: So now we need to tag classes as 'intended to be used for inheritance' or not?  You are just creating complexity and adding special case behavior for no reason other than to let developers be lazy when inheriting from a class.

Comment: @voo I wanted to make the same point as sr222. I don't really understand what has to do with DRY, however I agree about the mixin thing, even if you won't be making a mixin for bare `object`s.

Comment: @sr2222 Yeah it's generally a really good idea to specify the inheritance contract, see EJ and co (eg c# language design) for the reasoning. Lots of people got quite the surprise when inheriting from `HashMap` in java because that wasn't done sensibly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Raymond Hettinger's [super() considered super](http://rhettinger.wordpress.com/2011/05/26/super-considered-super/) has some information about how to deal with this. It's in the section "Practical advice".

Answer (score 4):

You can see http://bugs.python.org/issue1683368 for a discussion.  Note that someone there actually *asked* for it to cause an error.  Also see [the discussion on python-dev](http://www.mail-archive.com/python-dev@python.org/msg22025.html).

Anyway, your design is rather odd.  Why are you writing every single class to take unspecified `*args` and `**kwargs`?  In general it's better to have methods accept the arguments they need.  Accepting open-ended arguments for everything can lead to all sorts of bugs if someone mistypes a keyword name, for instance.  Sometimes it's necessary, but it shouldn't be the default way of doing things.

Comment: I'm writing a mixin, so I don't usually know my parent. Now I could just *not* call super from my mixin code and expect the actual object to call the parent constructor explicitly, but that seems prone to errors and redundant. But thanks for the bug report, I'll read it :)